# if any method we have from html to run a function with onclick event from external html page?

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, json

I have 2 html files a.html, b.html can i edit a.html elements by onclick from b.html file?
if any possible ways

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>s
    
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    
     <p id="demo"></p>
    
     <p>A function is triggered when the button is clicked. The function outputs some text in a p 
     element 
     with id="demo".</p>
    
     <script>
     function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
     }
     </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please let me know how this relates to `java` ?

Comment: sorry its required minimum 5 tags I don't know more content related to this so I just fill fill with a tag. I am so sorry

Answer (score 0):

1. localStorage.setItem
2. addEventListener

Comment: Please try to give some explanation, so that any future audience or the person who asked the question know what exactly you are trying to say.